# How do I make deleted DB data reflect in my mount() rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm intending to use the function Delete Post() in Post.vue component to erase the post and route it to the Index screen.

```
    Delete Post() {
    if (this.post.title) {
    this.$axios
    .delete("http://localhost:50598/api/post/" + this.post.id, {
    "content-type": "text/json"
    })
    .then(this.$router.push({ name: "Index" }))
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response);
    });
    }
    }
```

Although deleting database data and routing to the Index screen are good, there is a problem where deleted posts are displayed until the Index page is refreshed.

```
    mounted() {
    this.$axios.get("http://localhost:50598/api/post").then(result => {
    this.posts = result.data;
    });
    }
```

How can I reload Index page without deleted post?

Comment: are you using stores ?

Comment: No I'm not yet... I have store in project but don't have enough  knowledge about it.